# Running Service periodically at a given time in Android 2.2

Tags: android, service

I want to run a service everyday at a given time. lets say I have an application and have a input field to enter the time and button. when i click the button my service needs to be scheduled to run everyday at the entered time. how can i do this.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a looke at the [AlarmService](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlarmService.html) example - that should pretty much cover it.

**EDIT:** You might also want to look at the [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) widget class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use standard Java mechanism ScheduledExecutorService: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html